# Error in dim(x) <- length(x) : invalid first argument, must be vector (list or atomic) in R using Tensorflow and Keras

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to create a model inside of R using tensorflow and keras. I keep encountering the error listed in the title when trying to actually fit the model with training data which in my case is a subset of a image dataset. The images have already been prepped and standardized to all be the same size. Code is included below.

```
#here, pic1 - pic 10 are each individual picture once they have been cropped 
pics <- list(pic1, pic2, pic3, pic4, pic5, pic6, pic7, pic8, pic9, pic10)

#creating train and validation split (I know these are small, just trying to get model running first)
train <- pics[1:5]
val <- pics[6:10]

#creating label sets
trainLabels <- read.csv('ddi_metadata.csv')
labels <- trainLabels$malignant
trainLabels <- labels[1:5]
valLabels <- labels[6:10]

model <- keras_model_sequential()
model %>%
  layer_dense(units = 256, activation = 'relu', input_shape = c(2352)) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu') %>%
  layer_dense(units = 3, activation = 'softmax')
summary(model)


# Compile model
model %>% compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
                  optimizer = 'adam',

                  metrics = 'accuracy')
#every step runs fine, error occurs at step below 
# Fit model
model_one <- model %>% fit(train,
                           trainLabels,
                           epochs = 30,
                           batch_size = 32,
                           validation_data =  list(val, valLabels))

#error: Error in dim(x) <- length(x) : invalid first argument, must be vector (list or atomic)

#have tried using as.vector(train) to fix, still encountered same error
```